# I have a column with multiple groups. I want each group as its own column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with two columns. The first column has the groups, and the second column has values.

I want each grouping to be a column, and I want all associated values under the appropriate column.

I prefer a tidyverse solution. If possible, I prefer a solution that automatically takes each group and creates a new column with the appropriate values under it. I do not want to manually type the headers.

This is what I have:

```
df <- data.frame(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
                 Value = c(2,2,2,3,3,3))
df$Group <- as.character(df$Group)
```

This is what I want:

```
want <- data.frame(A = c(2,2,2),
                   B = c(3,3,3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tidyverse`, we can use `pivot_wider` after creating a sequence column by 'Group'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(Group) %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = Group, values_from = Value) %>%
   select(-rn)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#      A     B
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     2     3
#2     2     3
#3     2     3
```

---

In `base R`, it can be one with `unstack`

```
unstack(df, Value ~ Group)
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), rowid(Group) ~ Group, value.var = 'Value')[, .(A, B)]
```